# Missing Keyboard Shortcuts on Tooltips in Blender 2.8 RC

Tags: interface

I decided to try the 2.8 Release Candidate. The YouTube [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8XyIYRW_2xk) introducing the interface shows Keyboard Shortcuts in the Tooltips. However, I'm unable to see any Keyboard Shortcut being displayed in any Tooltip. (See Image)

Is there a setting in Preferences that I should enable in order to see these?

[image: Screenshots Showing Missing Keyboard Shortcuts in Blender 2.8 RC]

Blender Details:
version: 2.80 (sub 74), branch: master, commit date: 2019-07-11 13:50, hash: 06312c6d2db8, type:
build date: Thu 07/11/2019, 09:59 AM

Windows Version: 1903 (build 18362.207)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Spacebar action is set to 'Search', there is no shortcut for the toolbar and so also none is displayed in the tooltip ([Source](https://developer.blender.org/T66914#721631))

[image]